# C++ VERTEX and EDGE classes don't work

Tags: c++, data-structures, graph

I made the class `vertex` and `Edge` for a graph but I don't understand why the `Edge`'s methods `GetVer1()` and `GetVer2()` don't work! I need to work with the pointers to the vertices for my project. Could someone help me?

`Vertex` code:

```
typedef class vertex *Vertex;

class vertex {
private:
    int Key;
    list<Vertex> Adj;
public:
    vertex() {}
    vertex(int k) { Key = k }
    ~vertex() {}
    void AddAdj(Vertex);
    int GetKey();
};

void vertex::AddAdj(Vertex v)
{
    Adj.push_back(v);
}

int vertex::GetKey()
{
    return Key;
}
```

`Edge` code:

```
class Edge {
private:
    Vertex V1;
    Vertex V2;
public:
    Edge() {}
    ~Edge() {}
    Edge(Vertex, Vertex);
    Vertex GetVer1();
    Vertex GetVer2();
};

Edge::Edge(Vertex a, Vertex b)
{
    V1 = a;
    V2 = b;
}

Vertex Edge::GetVer1()
{
    return V1;
}

Vertex Edge::GetVer2()
{
    return V2;
}
```

`Main` code:

```
int main()
{
    Vertex a(1);
    Vertex b(2);
    Edge e(a,b);

    Vertex v1 = e.GetVer1();
    cout << v1->GetKey(); //it doesn't work!

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How exactly do they not work? What results were you expecting and what results did you get? Please include this information in your question.

Comment: You are not defining v1. `Vertex v1 = e.GetVer1();`

Comment: It simply crashes! Yes I defined v1, I just forgot to copy it.

Comment: What exactly is the error message when it crashes. Have you used a debugger to determine where it crashes?

Comment: `typedef class vertex *Vertex;` is at best confusing, and at worst, a disaster waiting to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two problems.

First,

```
vertex(int k) { Key = k }
```

should be

```
vertex(int k) { Key = k; }
```

Second, with the lines

```
Vertex a(1);
Vertex b(2);
```

you are trying to call the `Vertex` constructor with integer arguments. But `Vertex` is defined as a pointer to a `vertex`. As such, there is no appropriate constructor. My compiler gives an error on these lines, but it sounds like yours may be initializing the pointers to addresses 1 and 2, which would almost certainly cause the crash.

Changing main to:

```
int main()
{
    Vertex a = new vertex(1);
    Vertex b = new vertex(2);
    Edge e(a,b);

    Vertex v1 = e.GetVer1();
    cout << v1->GetKey(); //it doesn't work!


    delete a;
    delete b;
    return 0;
}
```

will work. But, as noted in the comments, the use of the `Vertex` typedef as a pointer to a `vertex` is quite confusing.

Comment: Yes, I really confused the two instances.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use unnecessary typedefs like this:

```
typedef class vertex *Vertex;
```

Not only is it confusing as bcrist pointed out, it is the source of your problems.  You declared two "object-looking" things like this, and then proceeded as if they are objects when they're not:

```
Vertex a(1);
Vertex b(2);
```

These are really pointers, and thus are uninitialized.  However to the quick looker, they look like objects.  It doesn't cost anything to actually state that a pointer is being used:

```
vertex* a;
vertex* b;
```

Now it is clear that you have pointers and they need to point to a valid instance of vertex before you use them.

Comment: Yes, I really confused the two instances.
I often use typedefs but with different names.